# Is there a repository location for common queries of AACT using R

Tags: r, repository

I am new to accessing the clinicaltrials.gov repository in AACT using R.  As a health services researcher, I see this database to be of value for answering a number of questions.  Is anyone aware of an opensource file location where a series of potential master queries for this database might be stored? Thanks in advance for sharing your insight.

Comment: Hi Nancy. I'm afraid questions seeking recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: There is this [AACT using R](https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/r)...you'll additionally need AACT credentials, `RPostgreSQL` package...